# Short story about AI robot who kills all humans except a small group

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, dystopia, artificial-intelligence

Trying to remember the title of a short story about an AI robot computer who kills all humans out of resentment, but keeps a small group to torture. The group consists of one loner, who eventually saves the rest of the group by murdering them with an icicle, i think. The AI is very angry the others were saved, and eternally tortures the lone survivor, turning him into this jelly glob thing.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0qBlPa-9v_M

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Likely *[I Have No Mouth, and I Must Scream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Have_No_Mouth,_and_I_Must_Scream)* by Harlan Ellison

A mad computer is torturing a small group of humans. One of them eventually takes it upon himself to kill the others with an icicle.

> I drove the great ice-point ahead of me like a battering ram, braced against my right thigh. It
>   struck Benny on the right side, just under the rib cage, and drove upward through his stomach
>   and broke inside him. He pitched forward and lay still. Gorrister lay on his back. I pulled another
>   spear free and straddled him, still moving, driving the spear straight down through his throat. His
>   eyes closed as the cold penetrated. Ellen must have realized what I had decided, even as fear
>   gripped her. She ran at Nimdok with a short icicle, as he screamed, and into his mouth, and the
>   force of her rush did the job.

and the result

> AM has altered me for his own peace of mind, I suppose. He doesn't want me to run at full speed
>   into a computer bank and smash my skull. Or hold my breath till I faint. Or cut my throat on a
>   rusted sheet of metal. There are reflective surfaces down here. I will describe myself as I see
>   myself:
>   I am a great soft jelly thing. Smoothly rounded, with no mouth, with pulsing white holes filled
>   by fog where my eyes used to be. Rubbery appendages that were once my arms; bulks rounding
>   down into legless humps of soft slippery matter. I leave a moist trail when I move. Blotches of 
>   diseased, evil gray come and go on my surface, as though light is being beamed from within.

Answer (score 6):

This is Harlan Ellison's most famous short story, "I Have No Mouth, And I Must Scream."  The blob the protagonist is finally turned into in the end literally has no mouth (so he cannot possibly harm himself and take away the mad computer AM's last victim), hence the name, which is the story's last line.

Copies of the text (including the formatting between sections), can be found online by Googling.